# React : Focus on Froala Editor (On External Event)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus, wysiwyg, froala

How can I put my cursor (focus) on froala editor when I click an external button.

I have done the same in Angular with the help of jQuery.

```
$(<selector>).froalaEditor('events.focus', true);
```

But, In React, I want to do this, without jQuery.

> I am using npm package : react-froala-wysiwyg (version 3.0.6)

Thanks in Advance ...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
const ele = document.getElementsByClassName('fr-element')[0];
ele.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a ref to it. Use a state to toggle on and off. Your button will toggle the focus and then add an addEventListener to the Froala editor ref in useEffectLayout anytime the toggle changes.

NB: Show some code to make it easier.

Comment: ref property does not seem to be working with FroalaEditor component like it does with textinput and textarea.

Comment: You have to check the ref property. It might not be ref. I have seen a component that its ref was named inputRef (material-UI). So check.

Comment: Yes, I checked as per your suggestion, but there seem to be no similar property that can work like ref.